# How does App Engine handle HTTPS requests?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, https

I am moving my application to GCP App Engine, requests need to be HTTPS.

My server currently handles HTTPS requests with the HTTPS module. In all the example of demo apps they all serve only HTTP.

Are encrypted connections terminated and then passed to the app as HTTP requests and if so is this secure?

I know that you can set app.yaml to specify that all connections are 'secure' and use HTTPS but this seems not very secure as if that line is missing then traffic is now not encrypted but will still be served as the server is configured to serve HTTP traffic?

Comment: App Engine has a fronted load balancer that clients connect to via HTTP and HTTPS. The frontend terminates the connection and then calls your backend code. Your backend can detect the protocol used by the client and refuse HTTP origin requests. This link will help understand how requests are handled: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/how-requests-are-handled App Engine Headers: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/reference/request-response-headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GAE, connections between the load balancer and your app are always HTTP.  This is the case even if the original request was HTTPS.  The load balancer sets headers to let you know if the request was originally HTTP or HTTPS.

For most people, this is an acceptable security risk.  Requests behind the Google firewall are certainly much safer than requests outside of the Google firewall.

If this is not an acceptable security risk for you, then you cannot use GAE.

You can require that connections between the end user and the firewall are always HTTPS, such as by automatically redirecting HTTP to HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

When you miss `secure`, both HTTP and HTTPS can be served. See [this document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref).

> ***secure***
> Optional. Any URL handler can use the secure setting, including script handlers and static file handlers. The secure element has the following possible values:
>
> **optional**
>
> Both HTTP and HTTPS requests with URLs that match the handler succeed without redirects. The application can examine the request to determine which protocol was used, and respond accordingly. This is the default when secure is not provided for a handler.